# preg_match or eregi questions

Tags: php, javascript, regex

i have two questions.

1, i have a input

```
<input name="fruit" type="text" />
```

i only want to text field to allow 3 kinds of inputs with formats like no space, space and & for example "apple", "apple juice" or "apple_juice". how can i achieve this in javascript or php? sorry i am very bad at regex

2, i want to convert the follow string to some formatted string

for example

apple   converted to  apple
apple juice    converted to    apple_juice
apple & juice   converted to    apple_juice
apple&juice   converted to     apple_juice
apple_juice   converted to   apple_juice

how can i do this in php?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: What should happen for `a b c`? What are the characteristics of the three kinds of input? Or do you literally want to allow only these three inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a reason why to restrict the input if you convert it to an other format anyway. For example if you have `apple + juice`, why reject it and not convert it to `apple_juice` too?

This will convert all consecutive non-alphanumeric characters to one `_`:

```
$output = preg_replace('/[\W_-]+/', '_', trim($input));
```

Comment: cool, should be ok, the only thing is in part 1 question i want to limit the input of +, so only space or _ or & allowed, this is to stop all funny characters entered by bad users

Comment: @bluedream: But what is the problem if you convert them anyway in the end? Or are these questions not related to each other? I could also ask you why you even want to allow `&` and `space` if in the end you only want `_`.

Answer (score 0):

here's the regex pattern for it `/^(apple|apple\sjuice|apple_juice)$/`

Answer (score 0):

### 2.

You seemingly want to replace any non-letter characters with a single `_` underscore. This all time classic would do:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\W+/', "_", $str);
$str = trim($str, "_");   // in case there were any surroundings
```